# How to use grid on a loop of multiple images

Tags: php, mysql

In my code below, `id = "images"` is a grid and should be selecting multiple images from the database. but its only selecting one right now.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("
SELECT * 
  FROM images i 
  JOIN journal j
    ON j.journalId = i.journalId
  JOIN user u
    ON u.userId = j.userId
");
$stmt->execute();?>


<body>      
    <main>  
    <div id =full>  

    <?php while($row = $stmt-> fetch()) { ?>
    <div id = "userOne">

    <div id = "userInfo">
    <a href="profile.php"><img src="<?php echo($row["profilepicture"]);?>" alt="profile picture" width="30"/></a>   
    <div id ="grid">
    <h2 id = "one"><?php echo($row["name"]);?>"</h2>    
    <h3 id = "two"> 2 mins ago </h3>
    <h3 id = "three"> Following</h3>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id = "images">
    <div>
    <img class = "grid" src="<?php echo($row["moreimages"]);?>" alt="profile picture" width="200"/> 
    </div>
    </div>  

    <a href="journal.php"><h1><?php echo($row["title"]);?></h1></a>
    <h3><?php echo($row["experience"]);?></h3>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>

    </div>
    </main>

    <footer>
        <?php include("includes/footer.php"); ?>
    </footer>

</body>
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

I think you use left join instead of Inner join in your query
hope it will work